# Gujarati Unicode text on HTML formatted JLabel does not work (square box)

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts, jlabel

On my `JLabel`/`JButton` components etc. I use HTML to format text. This works very well in all languages except Gujarati.

I am using normal ASCII letters to encode the Gujarati letters, e.g.:

```
\u0aae\u0ac1\u0ab6\u0acd\u0a95\u0ac7\u0ab2\u0ac0
```

Will decode to:

```
મુશ્કેલી
```

When I put the text on a `JLabel`:

```
myJLabel.setText("\u0aae\u0ac1\u0ab6\u0acd\u0a95\u0ac7\u0ab2\u0ac0")
```

The text renders well to Gujarati.

But when I incorporate html-tags to it in order to format the text, it does not work any more and square boxes are shown (all other languages render well with html, including Arabic and Cyrillic letters). As soon as I am using html - tags with the Gujarati letters, this does not work any more and square boxes (unknown characters) are printed:

```
myJLabel.setText("<html>\u0aae\u0ac1\u0ab6\u0acd\u0a95\u0ac7\u0ab2\u0ac0<\html>")
```

I already used several hints I found for this issue, e.g. the following ones, but with no success:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: As an additional information: I use the "Rasa-Regular" - Font for Gujarati letters.

Comment: Works fine for me - Java 8/MacOS using `Lucida Grande` font - In most cases, where you get a "square box" instead of the character, it's an issue with the Font

Comment: You are putting \u0aae in Java source code, right? Java compilation is on the only step I can see that you are using that would interpret \u0aae as મ. Also (not sure if matters to jlabel), in HTML 5 text is not permitted content until you get down to [html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)/[body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body).

Comment: @DRAKU How do you set the font? Do you use myJLabel.setFont()? Or something else?

Comment: @TomBlodget Last time I checked, Swing did not support HTML5, also, in HTML5, `<body/>` is auto-opening, just as it used to be in the original HTML. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#tag-omission-in-text-html and https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#the-body-element

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the fonts shown in the output of this code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class GujaratiFonts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String gujaratiText
                = "\u0aae\u0ac1\u0ab6\u0acd\u0a95\u0ac7\u0ab2\u0ac0";
        Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        int count = 0;
        for (Font font : fonts) {
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(gujaratiText) < 0) {
                System.out.println(font.getName() + " can print this.");
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Supported Fonts: \t" + count);
        System.out.println("Installed Fonts: \t" + fonts.length);
    }
}
```

### Results *Here*

```
Arial Unicode MS can print this.
Nirmala UI can print this.
Nirmala UI Bold can print this.
Nirmala UI Semilight can print this.
Supported Fonts:    4
Installed Fonts:    440
```

### Note

Unless the app. is providing a `Font` suitable for the language being displayed, it makes sense to run that code & choose a font that is already installed, **every time the app. runs**. The installed fonts will change across different computers, and over time.